# How to make a link in @Html.LabelFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on the asp.net mvc project. I am generating a name with this code -

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ReturnAirTemperature, new { style = "position: absolute;top: 310px;left: 18px;z-index: 10000;font-weight:bold" })
```

I have this model for it -

```
[Display(Name = "T(return)")]
public decimal ReturnAirTemperature { get; set; }
```

How can I create a link on "T(return)" text ?

Comment: `LabelFor()` generates a `<label>` (not an `<a>` tag). You can use `@Html.ActionLink()` (and `Html.DisplayNameFor()` to get the display name)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
<a class="" href="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new { id=item.MyID })">         
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>       
            <span class="sr-only">@Html.LabelFor()</span>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use like this:

```
<label for="@nameof(Model.ReturnAirTemperature )">u must agree our <a href="google.com">terms and conditions</a></label>
```

Comment: Please elaborate about your answer, so OP can learn from it.